# Understanding a corollary in Artin

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation

Artin's Proposition 5.13 states:

> Let $\varphi: G \to G'$ be a group homomorphism with kernel $N$, and let $a,b$ be elements of $G$. Then $\varphi(a) = \varphi(b)$ if and only if $b = an$ for some eleent $n \in \mathbb{N}$, or equivalently, if $a^{-1} b \in N$.

Artin comments that when the kernel is trivial, (5.13) can be rewritten as;

> A group homomorphism $\varphi: G \to G'$ is injective if and only if its kernel is the trivial subgroup.

I know how to prove that the latter is true, but I do not see how it's simply a rewriting of the proposition. If I rewrite 5.13, we have $\varphi: G \to G'$ a homomorphism with kernel $N = \{e\} \subset G$ a subgroup. Then $\varphi(a) = \varphi(b)$ if and only if $b = ae = a$ or, equivanently, if $a^{-1} b \in \{e\}$. The forward implication $\varphi(a) = \varphi(b) \implies a = b$ is the definition of $\varphi$ being injective. The backward implication $a = b \implies \varphi(a) = \varphi(b)$ is just the definition of a function being well-defined. So this proposition, rewritten, only gives that if a group homomorphism has a trivial kernel, it is injective. It does not give the backward implication that injectivity implies that the kernel is trivial, though we could retrace our steps and prove it quite easily.

Am I missing something, or is Artin just considering this a rather trivial jump for the reader to fill in?

Answer (score 1):

The backwards direction is that if $\phi$ is injective, then $\ker \phi = \{ g \in G : \phi(g) = \phi(e_G) \} = \{ e_G \}$.

Comment: I don't know if I understand, though this would definitely make sense. The if and only if is given after the assumption of $N$. I agree that this is an accurate statement, but how do I get it from the proposition?

Comment: @user861776 because the prop tells you that $\ker \phi = \{ a^{-1} b : \phi(a) = \phi(b) \}$.

Comment: I thought that was the second half of the implication -- that $\phi(a) = \phi(b)$ implies $a^{-1} b \in \mathrm{ker}(\phi)$?